# What is this pipe that is uncovered outside of my brick wall?

Tags: pipe, exterior, hole

I found a mysterious hole on my outside brick wall (red arrow in image) - it is located above the 2nd floor's bathroom and below the 3rd floor's bathroom (hence the windows above and below).

It's a bit high up so I dangled my phone camera and got some close ups which looks like a PVC pipe (oddly it's right next to another gray pipe). It is left open and I worry it's where I am getting water coming into the house. Any idea what this pipe can be for and if I can close it off?

Thank you[image: Outside view]

[image: Upclose view]

[image: Upclose view 2]

Comment: That is the emergency drain pipe for the toilet for when the primary is blocked and you really need to go.  Probably the vent pipe for the bathroom exhaust fan.  Should have a cover on it.

Comment: Agreed, fan sounds likely, and should have a cover to both prevent nesting and reduce heat loss when not in use.

Comment: Thank you both! Do you have a suggestion of what cover would work here? I took a look at Home Depot just now and don't seem to see any that is made for a 2 inch pipe - for example, this is only available in 4 inch: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-4-in-Louvered-Exhaust-Hood-HS4W-18HD/205046974

Comment: A 4" louver will cover a 2" pipe, just roughly center it over the pipe and screw it in. You'll need to drill holes into the brick and insert anchors - screws directly into the brick won't hold too well.

Comment: Just in case this is not a weird pipe, turn on exhaust fans and see if air comes out.  A piece of paper or a feather on a stick will help.

Comment: Just tried this and even when I turned on all the exhaust fans one by one and then all of them together, don't quite see my paper towel taped on swiffer move... I was Googling some more and one other thing I saw is an "Air conditioner condensate drain line". I do have central air conditioning in the house - would this possible be that?